# Child component do not see Parent Component state updates

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-state-management

I'm new to React and i'm facing an issue related to state updates.

I have a Parent Component. In the Parent Component constructor, i create multiple instance of a Child Component.

Using the state of the Parent Component, i display one of the Child Component instance.

Instances of Child Component have some Parent Component state value passed as props.

The Parent Component state looks like this (i have simplify the code so it can be clearer)

```
displayedContainer: {...} // An Instance of Child Component
isLoading: false
```

The Parent Component constructor looks like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Create state
    this.state = {
        isLoading: false,
        displayedContainer: null
    };
    // Create all Child Component (Container)
    this.defaultComponent = <Container 
        isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
    ></Container>
    // Others Child Component are created the same way as above.
    // To clearify the code i have removed them.
}
```

And here is the render method

```
render() { 
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.displayedContainer}
            <div className="container-left-bar"></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

From there, i can switch from one Child Component display to another so the `state.displayedContainer` is working. But when the `state.isLoading` is getting updated, Child Components doesn't detect it. I think it's because i'm creating the Child Component in the constructor.

How should i do if i want to keep the logic of creating Child Components before rendered it but fix the issue of state updates not detected ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Why are you putting `<Container ...>` on the instance, instead of just returning it from the render method? `state.isLoading ? <Container ...> : ...`

Comment: Because I need to display the `state.displayedContainer` which can be updated. If i directly render the `<Container ...>` i won't be able to render another `<Container ...>`, am i wrong ?
Having the list of `<Container ...>` already created make it easy to display one or another.

Comment: It will be less error prone if you just derive your UI from `state` and `props` in the `render` method instead of storing React elements directly on the instance or in state.

Comment: The things is `<Container ...>` have something like at least 15 properties passed as `props` so that's why I found it easier to create it and store it in an array (for example), take the one i want to display and give it to `state.displayedContainer`.

Comment: Try to put that in the render method instead and I think your error will be resolved.

Comment: If i put the `<Container ...>` in the render method it suppose that i have to store the at least 15 properties (passed to the `<Container ...>`) in the Parent Component state to be able to switch from a `<Container ...>` to another ? Am i right ?

Comment: Where are you getting the props from currently that you give it in the constructor?

Comment: Hmm... from another Parent Component. Is this the answer you intended for ?

Comment: If you get it from another parent component, just pass it down in the render method. `<Container aProp={this.props.aProp} />`, or if you want to pass everything down you can spread the props: `<Container {...this.props} />`

Comment: Okey, i'll think again the architecture because i think i'm doing it wrong. But i keep wondering why the `<Container ...>` see updates of Parent Component state when it's directly rendering and not when it's created in constructor...

Comment: When you put it in the render method, a new `React.createElement(Container, ...)` is called every time the `state` or `props` update. When you store `React.createElement(Container, ...)` on your instance and use that, it will never be re-run, and the same element will be used forever.

Comment: Hm okey, so we should never created Child Component in constructor of Parent Component if they have some Parent Component state value passed as props ?

Comment: Just don't do that, at all. Derive all your UI from `props` and `state` in the render method.

Comment: Fine, i'll keep it in mind !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you render the `<Container />` only once, in the constructor. The rendered instance is in the memory (`this.defaultComponent`) and therefore when you call `this.setState` the child never gets updated - is not notified about the change of any prop. This code should go to `render()` method.

Think of it like this:
When React determines `this.setState` (e.g. you want to display other container then the current one), React calls `render()` method, and should rerender `<Container .../>` with updated props. But since the code for rendering the component is not in the `render()` method - code that tells the `<Container .../>` to use newest `isLoading` prop from the state, `<Container />` never really gets updated with new value of the `isLoading` prop (or any other prop).

You should achieve something like this:

```
    render() {
        ...
        let renderCurrentContainer = null
        if (...) {
            renderCurrentContainer = <Container isLoading={this.state.isLoading} ...otherPropsHere... />
        }
        else if (...) {
            renderCurrentContainer = ...
        }
        else if (...) {
            renderCurrentContainer = ...
        }
        return <...>
            {renderCurrentContainer}
        </...>
    }
```

If you're asking what to put into the if condition, you need to somehow mark which component to render currently, I'll leave that to your creativity, but you can use something like `currentRenderedContainerIndex` which can have values `{0, 1, 2}`, or `currentRenderedContainer` string from enum e.g. `{'FIRST_COMPONENT', 'SECOND_COMPONENT', 'THIRD_COMPONENT'}`

Then you would go with something like this:

```
if (currentRenderedContainer === 'FIRST_COMPONENT') {
    renderCurrentContainer = <Container isLoading= {this.state.isLoading} ...otherPropsHere... />
}
else if (currentRenderedContainer === 'SECOND_COMPONENT') {
    renderCurrentContainer = ...
}
else if (currentRenderedContainer === 'THIRD_COMPONENT') {
    renderCurrentContainer = ...
}
```